# javascript to > jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a script like:

```
<script>
function vatCalculation() {
    var netto = document.getElementById('netto').value;
    var lordo = parseFloat(parseFloat(netto) / parseFloat(0.8)).toFixed(2);
    var ritenuta = parseFloat(parseFloat(lordo) * parseFloat(0.2)).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('lordo').value = lordo;
    document.getElementById('ritenuta').value = ritenuta;
}
</script>
```

and the html is:

```
<input name="netto" id="netto" type="number" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" onchange="vatCalculation();" />

<input name="lordo" id="lordo" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />

<input name="ritenuta" id="ritenuta" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />
```

Now the value of var are showed inside the field, but if i want tho show it inside `<h1></h1>` tag, what i need to to? Need to use jQquery? (fore live results). What can i do?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[indexofh1].innerHTML = yourvar`

Comment: As a side note: `<input>` is one of those tags that *do not* require closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.createElement("h1")` and append somewhere, in my case to a `div`.

```js
function vatCalculation() {
  var netto = document.getElementById('netto').value;
  var lordo = parseFloat(parseFloat(netto) / parseFloat(0.8)).toFixed(2);
  var ritenuta = parseFloat(parseFloat(lordo) * parseFloat(0.2)).toFixed(2);

  document.getElementById('lordo').value = lordo;
  document.getElementById('ritenuta').value = ritenuta;
  
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var node = document.createTextNode('Lordo :'+lordo);
  var h2 = document.createElement("h1");
  var node2 = document.createTextNode('Ritenuta :'+ritenuta);
  h1.appendChild(node); h2.appendChild(node2);

  var element = document.getElementById("show");
  element.innerHTML = '';
  element.appendChild(h1); element.appendChild(h2);
}
```

```html
<input name="netto" id="netto" type="number" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" onchange="vatCalculation();" />

<input name="lordo" id="lordo" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />

<input name="ritenuta" id="ritenuta" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />
<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but if i want tho show in the html? If i press CTRL+U i can't see the tag h1 & h2 inside the show id, i need to generate pdf from my form's results

Comment: @user0111001101 you can't see by pressing CTRL+U because it's created dynamically but you can see by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I in inspect element that mean within pdf generation it will show fine.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<h1 id="res">Result : </h1>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
$("#res").html(lordo); //Here's what you need to display.
</script>
```

Use `#id` inside `$()` to call html element.